# Bolzano-Weierstrass in Metric Space

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I was wondering whether the *Bolzano-Weierstrass* Theorem ("in a finite-dimensional normed space, every bounded sequence has a converging subsequence") would hold on

- a finite dimensional linear space
- with some obscure metric (rather than a norm)

As a counter example, I considered $\mathbb R$ with the metric $d(x,y)=\min\{1, |x-y|\}$ with the sequence $x_n:=n, n\in \mathbb N$ that is bounded (as a set in $\mathbb R$) but not convergent in any subsequence.

Is this correct so far? Are there more general considerations on this issue?

Comment: “Every compact metric space is sequentially compact” is a general theorem of which Bolzano-Weierstrass is a corollary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works. You can also use the discrete metric in $\Bbb R^n$. Then every sequence is bounded, but only those with a constant subsequence have a convergent subsequence.

On the the other hand, asking whether it holds on a finite dimensional linear space makes no sense; such a space is not automatically endowed with a distance.